# What is the biblical explanation for each of the fingers?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hands-fingers

I remember learning once that each of the fingers served a different purpose. I don't recall if this was in Talmud or Shulchan Aruch. What do our sources say is the purpose behind each of the different fingers?

Comment: : [maybe the picture here?](http://he.wiktionary.com/wiki/קמיצה)

Comment: [Kesubos 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.5b.1)

Comment: Well, the thumb is to more easily hold things, the index finger is to point to things... I mean, what is it that you’re looking for?

Answer (score 1):

**Zeret**: The pinky finger. In Shemos 39:9 it is used as a measurement, which when doubled, serves as the length and width of the Kohen Gadol’s breastplate.

**Kemitza**: The ring finger. In the grabbing flour part of a kemitza offering, this was the finger it would start from, spanning to the *ama* and *etzba* fingers.

**Ama**: The middle finger. From the end of this finger to the elbow is the ama measurement for building and vessels.

**Etzba**: The pointer finger. Used to sprinkle blood of sacrifices on the alter.

**Godel**: The thumb finger. Used to purify a metzora with blood and oil.

<sub>([sourced](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.5b.1))</sub> 
￼ [image]
Picture from [wiki](http://he.wiktionary.com/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%94)

Comment: Add the source discussing the fingers from the Talmud(Shabbat or Pesachim?) and it would be an even better answer.